# Suspended users can edit the duplicate list if they have the dupehammer, for a small period after getting suspended

Tags: bug, account-suspension, dupehammer

For several hours after being suspended I could press the *Edit* button on the duplicate banner, enter the duplicate target dialogue, and then add and remove duplicate targets from the duplicate list.

I didn't take a screenshot and I didn't try pressing the submit button, but would it have worked?

Being able to enter the duplicate list dialogue might be a bug by itself since other functionalities (like flagging, commenting, editing, etc) have an error message and don't let you enter the dialogues.

Comment: I searched MSO and MSE for a report on this and couldn't find any post.

Comment: You should have tried it while you had a chance. Now they have no choice but to suspend you again so you can figure it out :)

Comment: @Laurel Lol, I thought about trying it a few minutes before the suspension ended *"for science"* but the dupehammer was revoked sometime the next day.

Comment: How was a dupe hammer revoked if it was earned by earning a gold badge in a specific tag?

Comment: @Ramhound It was revoked because the suspension causes its removal but only after several hours.

Comment: @Ramhound Tag badges are revoked if the user doesn't meet their criteria anymore, but that script only runs once every 24 hours. When a user is suspended, tag scores are recalculated as 0, revoking any tag badges. However, the user retains the hammer during the meantime between their getting suspended and tag badges getting recalculated.